# Using timestamp literals in a WHERE clause with bq tool

Tags: google-bigquery

I had a look at the BigQuery command line tool documentation and I saw that you are able to use timestamp literals in a WHERE clause. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/timestamp#queryingtimestampdata) shows the following example:

```
$ bq query "SELECT name, birthday FROM dataset.table WHERE birthday <= '1959-01-01 01:02:05'"
Waiting on job_6262ac3ea9f34a2e9382840ee11538ef ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+------+---------------------+
| name |      birthday       |
+------+---------------------+
| kim  | 1958-06-24 12:18:35 |
+------+---------------------+
```

As the dataset.table is not a public dataset, I build an example using the wikipedia dataset.

```
SELECT title, timestamp, SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS human_timestamp 
FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia 
HAVING human_timestamp>'2008-01-01 01:02:03' LIMIT 5
```

The example works on the BigQuery Browser but it does not on the bq tool. Why? I tried to use scape characters and several combinations of single and double quotes without success. It is a Windows issue? Here goes a screenshot:[image]

EDIT: This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem is due to the greater operator `>` in the Windows command line. It does not have anything to do with the google-cloud-sdk, sorry.

It seems that you have to use the scape to echo the sign in the command line: `^>`
[image]

I found it at [google groups (by Todd and Margo Chester)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/wfRbTJrpyFk), and the [official reference at Microsoft site.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/echo.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 2):

I know that "It works on my machine" isn't a satisfying answer, but I've tried this on my Mac and on a windows machine, and it appears to work fine on both. Here is the output from my windows machine for the same query you've specified:

```
C:\Users\Jordan Tigani>bq query "SELECT title, timestamp, SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS human_timestamp FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia HAVING human_timestamp>'2008-01-01 01:02:03' LIMIT 5"
Waiting on bqjob_r607b7a74_00000144b71ddb9b_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
```

Can you make sure that the quotes you're using aren't pasted smart quotes and there aren't any stray unicode characters that might confuse the parsing?

One other hint is to use the `--apilog=-` option, which tells BigQuery to print out all interaction with the server to stdout. You can then see exactly what is getting sent to the BigQuery backend, and verify that the quotes are as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the apilog hint, it helped me to realise that the > operator was not being parsed correctly.