# bq tool, bat file | escaping characters not working when CALL

Tags: batch-file, escaping, google-bigquery

Using bq tool I have no problem escaping the > operator with a caret ^:

`bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event^>1"`

However, when I CALL the exact same command through a bat file whe whole thing breaks down.

`call bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event^>1"`

I understand `call` is the problem here. I can't remove it, since I need to run additional commands after it (`bq extract` and `gsutil cp`). I've tried adaptations of what is shown on [Escape user input in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910380/escape-user-input-in-windows-batch-file), to no avail.

What's wrong here? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you are allowed to change bq.bat?

Comment: Thanks for writing. No, I can't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose bq.cmd itself contains something like this

```
set param1=%1
set SQL=%~2
python bigQuery.py --%param1% "%SQL%"
```

So the line `set SQL=%1` requires escaping the special characters.

But when you use `CALL`, the batch parser has an additional phase of escaping but before it also has a phase of doubling all carets!

So your string in `call bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event^>1"` is converted to
`"SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event^^>1"`

I think there is no solution with only carets to solve this problem.

But you can avoid this by simply defining a variable containing one caret

```
set "caret=^"
call bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event%%CARET%%>1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. I think there is a confusion here.

When a parameter is enclosed in quotes, it may include special Batch characters with no need to escape they; the only problematic case is when Delayed Expansion is enabled and the parameter include an exclamation-mark or caret. For example, this line works correctly:

```
bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event>1"
```

This way, the same line with a CALL command also works correctly:

```
call bq query "SELECT x FROM [presentation_dim.dim_events] WHERE event>1"
```

If you escape the greater-than sign this way `^>` and don't use CALL, the character passed is the same `^>` that is processed as a single `>` in bq.bat. However, if you use CALL, then the escape is duplicated and `^^>` is passed.

Conclusion: Don't escape the `>` character.

Comment: Thanks, Aacini. Apparently, bq requires > to be escaped, even when enclosed in quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356037/using-timestamp-literals-in-a-where-clause-with-bq-tool/22358001#22358001. I tried following your recomendations, but it didn't work. btw, bq is a python-based tool, so it may be a more complex file than our regular bat file. :-(

Comment: If bq command is not a `bq.bat` file, then it does NOT require a CALL in order to return to the calling Batch file! Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: It's a cmd file that triggers python code. It needs CALL to return to the original bat file. I'll keep exploring on the path you kindly suggested.

````excerpt from bq.cmd 
@echo off
rem Copyright 2013 Google Inc.

SETLOCAL

rem <cloud-sdk-cmd-preamble>
rem  CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR
rem  CLOUDSDK_PYTHON    
rem  CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_ARGS         (u)  python interpreter arguments
rem  CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES (u)  use python site packages

SET CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR=%~dp0..
SET PATH=%CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR%\bin\sdk;%PATH%

IF "%CLOUDSDK_PYTHON%"=="" (
  SET CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python.exe
)